# Can one correct intersecting geo with geometry nodes just like I did in Houdini?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has yet discovered a solution to modifiy and correct intersecting geometry in Blender using Geometry Nodes. The provided image shows a correction done in houdini using VEXpressions. I need this correction in order to get proper cloth simulation in Marvelous Designer later on.

EDIT:

this is the VEXpression used in houdini to correct the geo

```
vector sampleP = @P + @N * chf('offset');
float dist = volumesample(1, 0, sampleP);


if (dist <0){
    f@intersect = 1;
    @P -= @N * chf('N_amp');
}
```

Comment: Interesting Q. I can imagine quite a few possible approaches to the problem?.. what approach did your VEX take?

Comment: @RobinBetts I updated the question with Houdini Code. Looking forward to your ideas